# JSF: Get current and previous page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I get the current and previous page in JSF?
So I would like to know from which URL the user is coming (previous URL) and what is the current page.
Furthermore I would like to know the Page name (title from page) from current and previous page.

Current page can be get with, right?

```
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
```

Many thanks for help

Comment: Off-topic: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. On-topic. The 'external' context is a servlet context, all plain http. So you could easily try and see if plain http has a solution (JSF works on top of http/html/...) And guess what, it has... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874539/how-to-get-previous-page-url-from-request-using-a-servlet

Comment: I will try it, many thanks for your help

Comment: and how can I got the page title from a page ?

Comment: You set the page title on the current page. So store it somewhere in a request object if you need it. For the previous page, don't relay on it. Dangerous and bad practice. And effectively a **new** question

Comment: What do you mean with set? I want to GET the page title from the current page

Comment: New questions and discussions in new questions please